# How to let user to browse to a file to be copied with Inno Setup

Tags: installation, inno-setup

I need user to browse to a file, select it, and then have this file copied from selected source to app folder.

Following this post
[How to show/use the user selected app path {app} in InputDirPage in Inno Setup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4638306/how-to-show-use-the-user-selected-app-path-app-in-inputdirpage-in-inno-setup)
and Inno Setup documentation, i came to this piece of code:

```
[Files]
Source: {code:GetDBPath}; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: confirmoverwrite uninsneveruninstall;

[Code]
var
  SelectDBPage: TInputDirWizardPage;  
  DBPath: String;

procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
  SelectDBPage := CreateInputDirPage(wpSelectDir, 'Select file', 'Select file',    'Select file', False, '');
  SelectDBPage.Add('');
  SelectDBPage.Values[0] := ExpandConstant('{src}\DB.FDB');
  DBPath := SelectDBPage.Values[0];
end;

function GetDBPath():String;
begin
    Result := DBPath;
end;
```

My problem is to retrieve file path. At instruction 'Source: {code:GetDBPath}' i get an 'Unknown filename prefix {code:' error.
How can I refer to the selected file path in [File] section?

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Looks like you're confused. The [files] section is read at compile time from the script. The compiler then produces the installer containing all the files and instructions to install your program. The InitializeWizard is called at run-time (when the produced installer is run), so you can't display a wizard page to change the files included in your setup. This is very similar to the compile-time and run-time of programming languages.

Comment: What is not clear in your question is if you want to let the _user_ to select a file to include in your script at compile time, or if you want to let the _user_ to select a file in the target computer and move/copy that file to other location on that target computer at run-time.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the `external` flag to the `[Files]` entry. This means the source will be evaluated at run time and CAN include `{code:...}` constants.

You're also not getting the correct value in your `GetDBPath()` function. You're returning the value of `DBPath` that isn't updated after creating the page, instead of getting the latest value form the `SelectDBPage.Values[0]`.

Comment: External flag was what I need. Still it seems not to tak the correct value. I mean that when I select file from browse window, i don't see the file path change in input field, and at next step i dont't have the selected value

Comment: You're not reading the value back from the page. I've update the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm new to inno setup scripting. Thanks again.

Comment: @user2029958, don't forget to [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/179541) ;-) @Deanna, be careful with that `code` getter. It is called many times, even before the `InitializeWizard` event passes, so you might access the `SelectDBPage` object, which has no instance yet. See below... This comment disappear in few minutes, please do not respond to it...