# Setup/MSI - Multiple user input directories

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-installer, installation, inno-setup

I'm in need of a setup creation tool (preferably outputing MSI file but not necessary) that is able to prompt the user for a "core" installation directory, and then prompt a second time for a "runfile" directory.

I've messed around a bit in Visual Studio 2010 and with Inno Setup but can't seem to find a solution.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Take a look to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4638306/how-to-show-use-the-user-selected-app-path-app-in-inputdirpage-in-inno-setup

Comment: I found some great examples of different scenarios including multiple installation directories in the examples supplied with the Inno Script Studio 5.5.3... More specifically the CodeDlg.iss example.

Comment: Inno Setup precludes MSI, but does make it much easier :)

Comment: @chonerman: Note that those example files come with vanilla Inno, not the third party script studio.

Answer (score -1):

A list with the best tools available currently: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Installer#Tools

Comment: Nice list, but it doesn't really answer the question does it?

Comment: First products from the list can do this, from what I know WiX is the only alternative if a free software is required. If not, for example you can do this in Advanced Installer to browse for the "runfile" directory (for the install path there is a predefined dialog available by default) http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/qa-browse-for-folder.html

Comment: If you have extra information and know certain packages can do that, then please add that to your reply rather than just a link with no explanation or even a filter to ones that do what the OP asked for. [Link only answers are frowned upon and subject to deletion](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion), especially such wide ranging links.